# java legacy application - architecture maturity assessment tool

Tags: java, architecture

I have just inherited a java based web product. It is around 7 years old and have around 750,000 lines of code. Most of it is bespoke development but chunks of it are jars that we have bought from 3rd parties. One of the tasks handed over to me by my management is to come up with a architecture check list and then assess this product on that basis.

The architecture check list needs to be generic i.e. it needs to talk about generic items like static analysis, structural analysis etc. Then it needs to talk about next level of details like unit test coverage (as a part of static analysis perhaps). Then it needs to talk about what is the numeric value (14% unit test coverage for example). Then it needs to talk about what is acceptable threshold (80% unit test coverage for example). Then it needs to talk about what tool (if possible) that can be used (cobertura for unit test coverage for example).

Question to group is, is there any one stop shop / tool - for this sort of architecture analysis / check that you might have used? I have already looked at SQALE and am not convinced that that is ready for consumption in my kind of area. I have looked at Stan4j and Structure 101 but they are only a small part of the picture.

So, question to group, if you have done anything on this line and know of a one stop shop / tool / framework, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [SonarJ](http://www.hello2morrow.com/videos) from Hello2morrow.

Answer (score 0):

There is an eclipse plugin [structure 101](http://www.headwaysoftware.com/products/structure101/plugins/) that allows you to *communicate and influence your architecture*.

Comment: Structure101 is great, but you should mention that this is a commercial application (the eclipse plugin is free, but works only with data created with the commercial main application)

Comment: I like Structure101. But I think SonarJ does that and more. The only problem with SonarJ is that it does not report back into Sonar and SQALE.